# Can't create composite primary key: Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory

Tags: java, hibernate

I try to create a composite primary key but can't.

My attempt (there is the [tutorial](https://Caused%20by:%20javax.persistence.PersistenceException:%20%5BPersistenceUnit:%20default%5D%20Unable%20to%20build%20Hibernate%20SessionFactory;%20nested%20exception%20is%20org.hibernate.MappingException:%20Could%20not%20determine%20type%20for:%20com.hltr.deardiary.model.dto.User,%20at%20table:%20personal_score,%20for%20columns:%20%5Borg.hibernate.mapping.Column(user)%5D) I used):

- User entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    @Column
    private String name;

    //getters, setters, equals, hashcode
}
```

- PersonalScore class:

```java
@Entity
public class PersonalScore {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PersonalScoreId personalScoreId;
    //getters, setters, equals, hashcode, constructors
}
```

- PersonalScoreId class (Primary key):

```java
@Embeddable
public class PersonalScoreId implements Serializable {
    
    private User user;
    private Date date;

    //getters, setters, equals, hashcode, constructors (noargs included)
```

That's all. In the result I got the error:

```
> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit:
> default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is
> org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for:
> com...model.dto.User, at table: personal_score, for columns:
> [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(user)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [EmbeddedId](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/EmbeddedId.html):

> Relationship mappings defined within an embedded id class are not supported.

What you need to do is replace the `User` field with a field for the user's id (`private long userId`), then use [MapsId](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/MapsId.html) in your `PersonalScore` class to add a relation with `User` using the `userId` field from the embedded id.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, but it seems I still haven't the needed result. Since in that, I need composite PK, but in this case, I got the table with a single PK (user_id) but I need both `user_id` and `date` for a composite key. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I mean the `personal_score` table - this table has the 'user_id` column as PK and the `date` column as a simple column, but I need the composite key `personal_score_id` with both field.

Comment: In addition - now I got the error `BLOB/TEXT column 'date' used in key specification without a key length`. I totally do not understand how to implement composite key now

Comment: @ValentynHruzytskyi the composite key can contain the `user_id` and the `date`. The only thing it cannot do is contain the `user` (entity) and the `date`. Regarding the error, can you show the key specification in the database (not code)?