# Spring JPA InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException Error

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. I'm trying to write a test and I'm getting this error on line `artistLabelRepository.save(artistLabel1);` in `ArtistLabelRepositoryTestIT`
`Can not set com.pandora.label.entity.Label field com.pandora.label.entity.ArtistLabelId.label to java.lang.Long`

These are the tables. the tables are already created and populated. I can alter the tables, but would like to not delete them and recreate them.

```
CREATE TABLE label (
    id               BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name             TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    parent_label_id  BIGINT REFERENCES label(id)
)
CREATE INDEX album_uid_idx ON album_label(id);

CREATE TABLE artist_label (
    artist_id         VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    label_id          BIGINT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (artist_id, label_id)
);

CREATE INDEX artist_label_idx ON artist_label(label_id);

ALTER TABLE artist_label ADD CONSTRAINT artist_label_fk FOREIGN KEY (label_id) REFERENCES label(id);
```

these are the Entities

```
class ArtistLabelId implements Serializable {
    private String artistId;
    private Label label;

    public ArtistLabelId() {
        // no arg constructor for JPA
    }

    public ArtistLabelId(String artistId, Label label) {
        this.artistId = artistId;
        this.label = label;
    }

    // setters and getters
}

@Entity
@IdClass(ArtistLabelId.class)
@Table(name="artist_label",
        indexes = {@Index(name = "artist_label_idx", columnList = "artist_id")})

public class ArtistLabel {
    @Id
    @Column (name = "artist_id")
    private String artistId;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "label_id")
    private Label label;

    public ArtistLabel() {
        // no arg constructor for JPA
    }

    public ArtistLabel(String artistId, Label label) {
        this.artistId = artistId;
        this.label = label;
    }

    // setters and getters
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="label")
public class Label {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="label_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name= "label_generator", sequenceName = "label_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private long labelId;

    @Column (name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_label_id")
    private Label parentLabel; //references parent label

    @Column(name = "create_date")
    private Timestamp createDate;

    @Column(name = "last_modified")
    private Timestamp lastModified;

    public Label(){
        //no-arg constructor for JPA
    }

    public Label(String name, Label parentLabel){
        this.name = name;
        this. parentLabel = parentLabel;
    }

    public Label(long labelId, String name, Label parentLabel){
        this.labelId = labelId;
        this.name = name;
        this.parentLabel = parentLabel;
    }

    // setters and getters
}
```

this is the repository

```
@Repository
public interface ArtistLabelRepository extends CrudRepository<ArtistLabel, Long> {}
```

and this is the test. i'm trying to save an artistLabel `artistLabelRepository.save(artistLabel1);`

```
@ActiveProfiles(value="test")
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Application.class})
public class ArtistLabelRepositoryTestIT {

    @Autowired
    ArtistLabelRepository artistLabelRepository;
    @Autowired
    LabelRepository labelRepository;

    @Test
    public void testFindByLabelId(){
        Label label = new Label(123L, "label1", null);
        labelRepository.save(label);
        ArtistLabel artistLabel1 = new ArtistLabel("artistId1", label);
        artistLabelRepository.save(artistLabel1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I answered to a similar question recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73517764/cant-create-composite-primary-key-unable-to-build-hibernate-sessionfactory/73517903#73517903. The problem is that you have an entity as `@Id`, and that's not allowed. You need to have a `Long` id field, and then a different property with `@MapsId`.